# ¿Cómo hacer para que mi app se siga ejecutando al bloquear el celular como spotify en React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Tengo una aplicación de radio `streaming` y al bloquear el teléfono cierra la app, supongo que es algo de permisos. La aplicacion corre si abro otra app pero al bloquear el telefono se cierra, sin embargo aplicaciones como `Spotify` no, ¿Cómo puedo imitar ese comportamiento? Gracias

```
"versionCode": 2,
    "permissions": ["FOREGROUND_SERVICE"],
    "package": "com.app.radiouno"
},
```

Tengo el servicio de `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` pero al bloquear igual se cierra.

Comment: Para ello debes de usar un servicio. Un Servicio es un componente de una aplicación que puede realizar operaciones de larga ejecución en segundo plano y que no proporciona una interfaz de usuario. Un ejemplo de ello: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=es-419

Comment: Gracias Chiscu, lo voy a probar y comento si me funciono